# How can I add this custom object to firebase

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, object

Currently I am getting an error

> Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom Object object (found in field Password)

Here is my code

```
const inputPasswordField = document.querySelector("#pwrd");
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(inputPasswordField.value, "Secret");
const PasswordSave = encrypted;
docRef.add({
Password: PasswordSave,
}).then(function(){
     console.log("status saved!");
        }).catch(function(error){
              console.log("got an error",error);
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` creates an object containing crypt data.

Declare `PasswordSave` like this:

```
const PasswordSave = encrypted.toString();
```

Comment: how do i then convert it back to the custom object for decrypting

Comment: var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(firebase_encrypt_stored, input_password);